# Why does the T109 night train from Beijing to Shanghai have such a long stop at Xuzhou?

Tags: trains, china, train-stations, timetables, xuzhou

I read on https://www.china-travel-guide.net/trains/T109/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200929010605/https://www.china-travel-guide.net/trains/T109/)) the following schedule for the T109 night train from Beijing to Shanghai:

| Station No. | Station Name | Arrive Time | Depart Time | Stop Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beijing | ---- | 20:05 | 0 mins |
| 2 | Tianjin West | 21:29 | 21:31 | 2 mins |
| 3 | Cangzhou | 22:28 | 22:30 | 2 mins |
| 4 | Dezhou | 23:37 | 23:40 | 2 mins |
| 5 | [Xuzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuzhou) | 3:43 | 4:11 | **28 mins** |
| 6 | Nanjing | 7:43 | 7:50 | 7 mins |
| 7 | Changzhou | 9:03 | 9:07 | 4 mins |
| 8 | Wuxi | 9:33 | 9:37 | 4 mins |
| 9 | Suzhou | 10:02 | 10:06 | 4 mins |
| 10 | Shanghai | 11:00 | 11:00 | 0 mins |

Why does the T109 night train from Beijing to Shanghai have such a long stop at [Xuzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuzhou)?

Comment: 28 minutes for a night train stop long? I used to travel on the European night trains in the '90's and a stop of half an hour was not even worth mentioning, stops up to two hours not exceptional. I bet a change over of staff or a connection and then there is the option of an other train on the same track.

Comment: @Willeke compared to other stops

Comment: Same here in Europe, even day trains often have one or a few longer stops. (Not sure about China as I can only go by published timetables, never been there yet.)

Comment: Note the website is hosting a Javascript virus

Comment: It might be meeting another train. The 30 minute wait is to give them some slop incase one of the two trains is delayed.

Comment: Xuzhou is the last station before the running time reaches 8 hours.

Comment: And the next stop seems to be a long time later, going over the 10 hours by quite a bit.

Comment: My guess would be to refuel.

Comment: Even if they aren't meeting another train, this may be a "make up" stop. In other words, even if the train is delayed 20 minutes (making it late at all the 2 minute stops) it can get back on time at this stop by waiting only 10 minutes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These stops are fairly common for trains running for over 10 hours. The main reasons are two-fold: maximum working time for the drivers, conductors and crews, and administrative planning.

---

After several disasters due to driver fatigues, drivers and train conductors may not work for over 8 hours before having a required rest period (10 hours in certain cases; but 8-hour shift remains recommended and the rule of thumb).

A shift change for drivers will be required in Xuzhou in any case.

Although this alone usually does not require a 28-minute stop.

---

There are additional jurisdictional and administrative considerations.

Chinese Railways are divided into several Railway Administrations/Bureaus (sub-companies nowadays), each having "jurisdiction" over routes in a given region.

In principle, the trains within the region should be run by staffs from that region. There are many exceptions and this is no longer a hard rule nowadays but some effects persist.

Within the bureaus, there are also sub-divisions over particular routes/tracks.

The Beijing-Shanghai route involves two administrative bureaus, Beijing and Shanghai.

Xuzhou is also the first stop in Jiangsu, which is Shanghai Bureau, after Dezhou (Shangdong, in Beijing Bureau).

---

Xuzhou is also one of *the* most important rail hubs in China.

At the intersection of [Longhai railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhai_railway) and Beijing-Shanghai railway, it serves as an important connection point.

It also has facilities that can carry out many maintenance operations if necessary.

---

The sister train T110 (in the other direction, Shanghai-Beijing) has a long stopover in Changzhou instead, a couple hours after departure from Shanghai. Before the stopover was in Nanjing.

If I had to guess, I would say it's to reduce the burden on Xuzhou station, which is already overloaded.